# Does SSD persistent storage improve MS SQL Server FILESTREAM performance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, solid-state-drive

Is it true that having an SSD persistent storage disk instead of an ordinary HDD storage disk on a server improves the performance of Microsoft SQL Server FILESTREAM operations like streaming a video stored in the database?

If so what is the difference in performance of the FILESTREAM operation and is it worth spending the extra money on SSD on a server ?

Comment: Why the question? It should be obvious that SSDs are a lot faster than HDDs in all situations. Is there another concern apart from transfer rate and IOPS ?

Comment: SSD is much more expensive than HDD, and when you are provisioning disk space on a cloud server in TBs it makes it a huge difference in terms of price. That's why I was wondering if its worth it with respect to the SQL Server FILESTREAM operations as I had mentioned in my question.

Comment: That's a question that only *you* can answer. How many IOPS do you need and how much do they cost? Although you'll find that the price difference is *not* big if you consider IOPS/$. Furthermore, cloud providers sell IOPS not HDD/SDDs. You may have to try hard to actually get an HDD these days. What you get when buying "HDD" is reduced IOPS on SSD arrays

Comment: you can use ssd for buffer pool

Answer (score 2):

There is a dramatic performance increase.  The amount of difference depends on many other considerations from the size of the files to the other hardware being utilized.  How much traffic you will have at peak and on average.

Is it worth it?  That is a question only you can answer.  Many applications have been built and perform well before SSD became available.  Many continue to be built and perform well using HDD even now that SSD is relatively affordable.

I found the following to be a good article on the topic:
An HDD might be the right choice if:

> You need lots of storage capacity, up to 6TB (though with SMR
>   technology new drives can have up to 10TB) Don’t want to spend much
>   money Don’t care too much about how fast a computer boots up or opens
>   programs - then get a hard drive (HDD). An SSD might be the right
>   choice if:
>
> You are willing to pay for faster performance Don’t mind limited
>   storage capacity or can work around that (Again, SSDs are working on
>   this “con”)

http://www.storagereview.com/ssd_vs_hdd